# Bootstrap container is not full width (white spaces on left and right side of screen)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have written some markup for a navigation bar on my webpage, now I am trying to move onto the next section, and I noticed when I was adding another section it doesn't expand the full width: [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWhbk.png)

I added a white background to that section, and the body's background is black. Here's some markup and CSS:

**HTML Sample:**

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- fun markup here -->
    </div>  
</header>
<section id="work">
    <div class="container"></div>
</section>
```

**CSS Sample**

```
section#work {
    padding: 100px 0;
    background-color: white;
}
```

I believe I have left out all irrelevant information, but if I did leave out something important that you also need, please let me know.

Comment: Try adding container-fluid instead of container. If still doesn't work create a fiddle/plnkr. It will be easy for us to understand.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) that reproduces the problem described in your question. See [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer here is to use `container-fluid`.

Please check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ya6z789x/1/

As you can see the first `container` class (simply `container`) has a set width of 1170px at larger viewports, 970px at slightly smaller and so on (it reduces as you reduce viewport size).

The second example, `container-fluid`, is set to 100% width of its parent. Meaning if your `header` element doesn't have a width defined, the `container-fluid` class will stretch to the full width of the window.

Alternatively, if your `header` element had a width of say 900px (third example), placing a `container-fluid` directly as a child of it will make the `container-fluid` element have a width of 900px. Note, you may need to expand the viewport of the fiddle to see this in action.